# Unable to Push to Azure Registry with docker-maven-plugin

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry, docker-maven-plugin

I've followed this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-azure

However, although I set the credentials in settings.xml for maven, I still get this error:

```
[WARNING] Failed to push apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io/apiefrontdoor, retrying in 10 seconds (5/5).
[INFO] Pushing apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io/apiefrontdoor
The push refers to repository [apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io/apiefrontdoor]
c7f1d24c6c55: Preparing
a46d8ce138df: Preparing
42fd82c87bc8: Preparing
ceaf9e1ebef5: Preparing
9b9b7f3d56a0: Preparing
f1b5933fe4b5: Waiting
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:36 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-02T18:24:11-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:build (default-cli) on project apiefrontdoor: Exception caught: unauthorized: authentication required -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:build (default-cli) on project apiefrontdoor: Exception caught
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception caught
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:151)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: unauthorized: authentication required
    at com.spotify.docker.client.AnsiProgressHandler.progress (AnsiProgressHandler.java:55)
    at com.spotify.docker.Utils$DigestExtractingProgressHandler.progress (Utils.java:191)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.ProgressStream.tail (ProgressStream.java:77)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$ResponseTailReader.call (DefaultDockerClient.java:2754)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$ResponseTailReader.call (DefaultDockerClient.java:2738)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apieproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>apiefrontdoor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>frontdoor</name>
    <description>APIE Project Landing Project</description>

    <properties>
       <jib-maven-plugin.version>2.3.0</jib-maven-plugin.version>
       <azure.containerRegistry>apiefrontdoor</azure.containerRegistry>
       <docker.image.prefix>apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io</docker.image.prefix>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ....
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
              <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                 <from>
                     <image>mcr.microsoft.com/java/jre:8-zulu-alpine</image>
                 </from>
                 <to>
                     <image>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</image>
                 </to>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
               <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.9.1</version>
               <configuration>
                  <authentication>
                     <serverId>azure-auth</serverId>
                  </authentication>
                  <resourceGroup>apieproject</resourceGroup>
                  <appName>apiefrontdoor</appName>
                  <region>Central US</region>
                  <containerSettings>
                     <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                  </containerSettings>
                  <appServicePlanName>ASP-apieproject-ae27 (P1v2: 1)</appServicePlanName>
                  <appSettings>
                     <property>
                        <name>PORT</name>
                        <value>8080</value>
                     </property>
                  </appSettings>
                 </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <serverId>${azure.containerRegistry}</serverId>
                    <registryUrl>https://${docker.image.prefix}</registryUrl>
                    <dockerDirectory>docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is my settings.xml

```
<servers>

    <server>
     <id>azure-auth</id>
      <configuration>
         <client>my-client</client>
         <tenant>my-tenant</tenant>
         <key>my-key</key>
         <environment>AZURE</environment>
      </configuration>
   </server>
   <server>
        <id>apiefrontdoor</id>
        <username>my-username</username>
        <password>my-password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

I can independently login to the Azure Container Registry using 'docker login' so that's not a credential issue. But although the project builds successfully, I can't push it to the same registry. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue per [this discussion trail](https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/278)

- As stated in the discussion, an Azure Container Registry service principal should be created with the permissions AcrPush and AcrImageSigner. Therefore, please don't use the container registry access keys for this.
- Afterward, instead of running a combo of build and push like this:

  ```
        mvn docker:build -DpushImage
  ```
- I separated these, after login to docker registry of course, the command into two distinct ones:

  ```
     a) mvn docker:build
     b) docker push <repo_name>.azurecr.io/<repo_name>:latest
  ```

Note: 'latest' was configured as my tag. If you used a different tag for versioning, please replace 'latest' with the latest version you just build

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the problem is the id in the server for settings.xml file and docker.image.prefix in pom.xml file. It shoudld exactly match. Read example from [url](https://github.com/microsoft/todo-app-java-on-azure/blob/master/doc/deployment/deploy-to-azure-container-service-using-maven-plugin.md) to know more about it.

Comment: I check values are same.But didn't help. Authentication suppliers used are: ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier, FixedRegistryAuthSupplier. Can that be the issue?

Comment: [INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:push (default-cli) @ apiefrontdoor ---
[INFO] Pushing apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io/apiefrontdoor
The push refers to repository [apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io/apiefrontdoor]
[WARNING] Failed to push apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io/apiefrontdoor, retrying in 10 seconds (1/5). Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.2.2:push (default-cli) on project apiefrontdoor: Exception caught: unauthorized: authentication required

Comment: In the sample above, pom.xml contains       
<docker.image.prefix>apiefrontdoor.azurecr.io</docker.image.prefix>

whereas in settings.xml file contains
        <id>apiefrontdoor</id>

Can you trying adding above in the settings.xml file and try again?